# Feign client - How do I change the read timeout option value in runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a configuration in `application.yaml` file :

```
service-api:
  url: "https://serviceapi.demo.com"
  connectTimeout: 2000
  readTimeout: 2000
```

But, the thing is, that in runtime I'd like to configure a different timeout for specific business flow (method) that's using that Feign client.